# Access Default Window Color Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, window, nscolor

I have an `SKView` with a picture of a keyboard in a window as shown below. I would like the background color of the `SKScene` it's presenting to be the same color as the window behind it, so that it would appear as if the keyboard was just in the window, and not in something else that was in the window. After consulting the `NSColor` documentation, I tried setting the background color of the `SKScene` as `NSColor.windowBackgroundColor()`. The color below is what I got. I'm assuming there was some kind of error and so it defaulted to black. That being said, how do I access the default color of a window?

[image]

Comment: Is your `SKView` presenting a scene (`SKScene`)? Have you tried setting the `backgroundColor` of the scene object, instead?

Comment: @KenThomases Sorry I meant to say `SKScene`. I'll change that right now...

Comment: What color was there before you tried setting the scene's background color? Experiment with setting the scene's and/or the view's background color to `UIColor.clearColor()` and the view's `allowsTransparency` to true.

Comment: If I did `self.view!.allowsTransparency = true` then using a clear color (`NSColor.clearColor()`) or what I was doing before (`NSColor.windowBackgroundColor()`) both worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `SKView`'s `allowsTransparency` to true and then set the `SKScene`'s `backgroundColor` to `NSColor.clearColor()`.

I think that using `windowBackgroundColor()` gives black if the view doesn't allow transparency and works if it does because it's effectively being translated to `clearColor()` by "accident". `windowBackgroundColor()` is a bit strange. It's not in either an RGB nor a gray-scale color space and it can't be converted to either of those. I'm guessing that `SKScene` tries to convert the background color to the RGB color space and, when that fails, it uses `clearColor()` as a fallback.